# How do you read to files and use the files to create two new files?

Tags: java

I have to read a file with the year best actress and movie. Then I use that file to create two new files, one with year and the actress, and one with the year and movie. The file is like this:

```
2002  Nicole Kidman   
The Hours 
2003 Charlize Theron   
Monster 
2004 Hilary Swank   
Million Dollar Baby 
2005 Reese Witherspoon   
Walk the Line 
2006 Helen Mirren   
The Queen
2007 Marion Cotillard 
La Vie en Rose
2008 Kate Winslett
The Reader
2009 Sandra Bullock
The Blind Side
2010 Natalie Portman
The Black Swan
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class BestActress{
       public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("BestActress.txt"));
         while(reader.hasNextLine()){
        int yearNumber=reader.nextInt();
        String text=reader.nextLine();
        actressLine(text, yearNumber);
        String textt=reader.nextLine();
        movieLine(textt, yearNumber); 
     }   
  }

  public static void actressLine(String text, int year)throws FileNotFoundException{
     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("YearBestActresses.txt"));
     Scanner data = new Scanner(text);
     while (data.hasNext()){
        String actressName=data.nextLine(); 
        writer.println(year+actressName); 
        writer.close();
     }
  } 
  public static void movieLine(String textt, int year)throws FileNotFoundException{
     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("YearBestActresMovies.txt"));
     Scanner data=new Scanner(textt);
     while(data.hasNext()){
        String movieName=data.nextLine();
        writer.println(year+" "+movieName);
        writer.close();
     }
  }

  }
```

The file that is created only says the last year so 2010 Natalie Portman and 2010 The Black Swan.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your program.

First and foremost, each of the methods, when it receives the text of one line, opens a writer, writes the contents of the string, and closes the writer.

Opening a writer, by default, clears the file. If there was data in it that was written in a previous iteration, it gets removed. Besides, opening and closing are heavy operations and should be done only when needed.

What you should do is open the two files for writing before going into the read loop in `main`, and pass the writer objects as parameter to your methods. Then in the methods you can just write the one line to the file.

Close the two files after your loop ends. All of this is best done with a [try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct.

Other problems:

- You don't really need to create a scanner on the data item you passed to the method. You can just write it directly to the writer.
- The read loop in your main program is dangerous. It checks if there is a next line, and then reads two lines. What if there is only one next line? There are two main strategies to deal with this:

  1. Put the second read in an `if ( reader.hasNextLine() )`. This ensures there is still another next line.
  2. Keep a flag (boolean) that tells you if you are currently reading the year and actress line or the movie line, and read only one line in each round. If the flag tells you it's the first, keep it in a variable. If it's the second, write both of them. Remember to change the flag after each line.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are recreating the `PrintWriter` objects every time you write a new line. Each time you do that it deletes and recreates the file. That's why you only see the last output in your files.

Create the writers beforehand and pass them into your methods that write the lines. (And then of course you need to move the `close()` methods into the outer method as well.) Something like this:

**EDIT:** Simplified `actressLine` and `movieLine` as @laune suggests in the comments.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BestActress {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("BestActress.txt"));

        PrintWriter writer1 = new PrintWriter(new File("YearBestActresses.txt"));
        PrintWriter writer2 = new PrintWriter(new File("YearBestActresMovies.txt"));

        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            int yearNumber=reader.nextInt();
            String text=reader.nextLine();
            actressLine(text, yearNumber, writer1);
            String textt=reader.nextLine();
            movieLine(textt, yearNumber, writer2); 
        }   
        writer1.close();
        writer2.close();
    }    

    public static void actressLine(String text, int year, PrintWriter writer) {
        writer.println(year + text); 
    } 

    public static void movieLine(String text, int year, PrintWriter writer ) {
        writer.println(year + " " + text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the Scanner and while loop in methods actressLine and movieLine are useful: omit. Just the writer.println is sufficient.

Comment: Great point, @laune, I've simplified the methods as you suggest.